# Menu on website not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

If I'm honest I feel a bit stupid asking this question on here as the answer will most likely be very simple, but I'm currently at my wits end trying to find the solution.

I have two web pages which use identical code and the same style.css file but use different tags, allowing me to alter the colour of the menus, header on the page etc.

The following one is working correctly

http://www.dtlsports.co.uk/poolIndex.php

However on this one, the menu has lost its colour and shifted down incorrectly.

http://www.dtlsports.co.uk/squashIndex.php

Can anyone spot the difference between the two that will make one work and the other not? I assume you'll be able to inspect all the necessary stuff on the pages themselves, but if not just let me know and I'll put it all on here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't see your problem, both the menues work when I test them, and non of them are shifted down or anything.

Comment: Please include enough information in your question to reproduce the problem. Assuming you fix your site, no one else will be able to benefit from the solution here!

Comment: My problem was resolved about 8 mins after I asked the question using the solution I accepted below. Adding 'display: block' to the nav section of my CSS file sorted out all the problems on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you needed to add display:block

```
  navQ {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFCC00, #FFCC00) repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
        border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
        border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        color: #FFCC00;
        display: block;
        height: 44px;
        margin: -37px auto 0;
        min-width: 800px;
    }
```

you are missing the following CSS style

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, navP, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the second one is missing a display:block;

http://puu.sh/5arNI.jpg